# Cannot unwind or Continue and Edit if Assert throw

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, mstest, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to do Edit/Continue in VS2015 Debugger.
This works 100% in VS2013.
But, once I hit an `Assert.` I keep getting cannot Unwind errors.

I have tried adding `AssertFailedException` to CLR Exceptions in `Exception Settings`. And I tried toggling Debugging settings: `Enable Just My Code`. And `Unwind the call stack on unhandled exceptions`.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TEST()
    {        
        int a = 5;
        int b = 1;
        Assert.AreEqual(a, b);
        throw new AssertFailedException("THIS IS OK");
        int c= a + b;
     }
```

UPDATE:
Same fail when I tried several versions of the Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualitTools.UnitTestFramework library. 10.0.0 & 10.1.0 (file versions 12 and 14). I'm now trying the VS2015 Update2RC.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it is working on VS2019.

In VS2019, Go to Debug > Windows > Exception Settings will show up "Break When Thrown" window.

Expand Common Language Runtime Exceptions
Check `<All Common Language RunTime Exceptions not in this list>`
Then you can unwind when Assert occured exceptions.